# not getting data in laravel 5.4 controller of dynamically created array of form input using jquery in view file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have created a form in view file of my laravel 5.4 app where i can add more input fields using jquery `clone()` function. in this form i also use jquery select2 plugin.
 Here is form:

```
<form name="tempform" action="{{route('temppris.store')}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}                                          
<table  class="table table-hover small-text" id="tb">
    <tr class="tr-header">
    <th >Sl.No.</th>
    <th class="col-lg-2" >Type</th>
    <th class="col-lg-3">Medicine  Name</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col-lg-2">Dosage</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col-lg-2">Duration</th>
    <th>Total Qty</th>
    <th class="col-lg-1"> Remarks</th>
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="slno[]" style="width:100%;" readonly></td>
    <td ><select name="meditype[]" class="meditype" style="width:100%;"></select> </td>                                                    </td>
    <td class="col-lg-4"><select name="medicine[]" class="medicine" style="width:100%;"></select></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="1" class="dos input-sm" style="width:40px;" min="1" name="dos[]" step="0.1"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-2"><select class="dosage" style="width:100%;" name="dosage[]" ></select></td>

    <td><input type="number" value="1" class="NoOfDuration input-sm" style="width:40px;" min="1" name="NoOfDuration[]" min="1"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-2"><select class="duration" name="duration[]" style="width:100%;"></select></td>
    <td><input type="number" class=" total" min="1" name="total[]" style="width:50px;"></td>

    <td class="col-lg-2"><select name="remarks[]" class="remarks" style="width:100%;"></td>
    <td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Doctor Advice</label>
                                <textarea name="docadvice" id="docadvice" class="form-control"></textarea> 
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success">Save Template</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="doc_id" value="{{Auth::user()->doc_id}}">
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Here is my jquery codes:

```
$('#addMore').on('click', function() {
                    $(".meditype").select2('destroy');
                    $(".medicine").select2('destroy');
                    $(".remarks").select2('destroy');
                    $(".duration").select2('destroy');
                    $(".dosage").select2('destroy');
                  var data = $("#tb tr").last().clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
                  data.find("input").val('');
                  data.find("select").val('');
```

I am a noob in controller code. so how can i get values of my all elements of form in controller . including those are dynamically created using jquery. i tried many times but only get null value or just value of first row. in jquery i initialize my select2 elements on form loading and also reinitialize them after cloning. so its working fine while i clone it. It may work for others because I search for this but not found on internet. But now getting values of this form in controller became headache for me. Trying from last 3 days but not working.
**UPDATE**
Here is Codes I am trying just for checking:

```
 $count=count($request->get('medicine'));
        $temppris->medicines=$count;
        $medicine=$request->get('medicine');
        foreach($medicine as $index => $value) 
        {
            $tempmedicine=new tempmedicine;
            $tempmedicine->medicine_dosage=$medicine[$index]=>$value;
            $tempmedicine->save();
        }
```

Comment: if anyone have any solution. but need more view of codes please ask her. thanks if you help..

Comment: Can you post the controller code you are trying?

Comment: here is codes i trying.

Comment: i Updates codes i am trying just to check . can you suggest where am i wrong??

Answer (score 0):

first make `dd` function inside the store function as `dd($request->medicine);`

please post the result then i will tell you what is the reason

Comment: this is your given function returning `array:1 [▼
  0 => "2"
]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply  try adding the medicines in the cloned from element and use the same `dd($request->medicine);` method if you get all the values inside array its working perfectly but if you are getting only the values of the original div element its definitely its naming problem

please post you result as follows by populating array so that i can view

```
for Example

array:2 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "3"
]
```

Comment: i tried it but when i checking value of `medicine[]` in jquery it giving all values see here, `function checkit()
{
    $('select[name="medicine[]"]').each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
} ` but when i trying to get it in controller after submitting it. its giving only first original select value.

Comment: It means you are returning array from your jquery so you should use `foreach()` function in your controller to make it's seperated values and then submit it.

Comment: i tried to use but in `dd($request)` it showing on 1 element in array.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
 $medicine=$request->get('medicine');
    foreach($medicine as $index => $value) 
    {
        $data = $value['medicine']; //here name will be your stored medicine name
        print_r($data);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: yes, i tried this and  using `dd($request->all());` it showing just one item in array. thats why i can't figure out problems in code.

Answer (score 0):

i figure out this friends. its just a silly mistake of placing my `<form>` tag and **closing it before closing of div that i have in my form.** in browser console showing warning error of unmatched tags but i just ignoring it. wasted 3 days to this silly mistake. you should all check such warning every time using form. i just place my form tag at the starting of my div in which i makin my tag..hope this will help others..